# Using obj-c typedef in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, typedef

I have a typedef as so:

```
typedef NSString VMVideoCategoryType;

extern VMVideoCategoryType *const VMVideoCategoryType_MusicVideo;
extern VMVideoCategoryType *const VMVideoCategoryType_Audio;
extern VMVideoCategoryType *const VMVideoCategoryType_Performance;
extern VMVideoCategoryType *const VMVideoCategoryType_Lyric;
extern VMVideoCategoryType *const VMVideoCategoryType_Show;
```

I've included this file in the bridging header. However, when I try to access `VMVideoCategoryType` in a Swift file I get an error:

`Use of undeclared type 'VMVideoCategoryType'`

Is there any way to make this work or do I have to completely re-define this type in Swift?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am a little bit speculating, but the reason seems to be that Objective-C
objects like `NSString` cannot be statically allocated (see e.g. [Are objects in Objective-C ever created on the stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663388/are-objects-in-objective-c-ever-created-on-the-stack)). If

```
typedef NSString VMVideoCategoryType;
```

were imported into Swift then you could declare a local variable

```
var foo : VMVideoCategoryType
```

which would be a `NSString` and *not* a pointer to `NSString`.

Note also that what you see in Swift as `NSString` corresponds to `NSString *`
in Objective-C.

If you define `VMVideoCategoryType` as a typedef for `NSString *`
then it *is* visible in Swift:

```
typedef NSString * VMVideoCategoryType;

extern VMVideoCategoryType const VMVideoCategoryType_MusicVideo;
// ...
```

Comment: This works for getting rid of Swift errors but then my previous type declarations in Obj-C using that type throw errors: `Implicit conversion of an indirect pointer to an Objective-C pointer to 'NSString *' is disallowed with ARC`

Comment: @Ramsel: You have to replace `VMVideoCategoryType *` by `VMVideoCategoryType` after that change (as I did in the extern definitions).

Comment: @Ramsel: If that does not help, please add the Objective-C code causing the problem to your question.

Comment: So in the end I didn't want to change the obj-c code that referenced the typedef, and I made a compromise to not refer to the type in Swift. I just reference it as a String. I am able to refer to the secondary constants of that type since they're pointers... This is an isolated case where we typedef'd an NSString "enum/struct" in Obj-c, so the isolated fix works for now.