# Reference class definition from prefix header in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, prefixheader.pch

I'm adding swift code to an existing Objective-C project. I'm having problems referencing a definition from the existing prefix header.

I have a class called MyClass, defined in Objective-C with .h:

```
@interface MyClass
+(instancetype)myClass;
-(void)doStuff;
@end
```

And .m:

```
@implementation MyClass
+ (instancetype) myClass
{
    // More to it than this, but this illustrates the setup
    return [[MyClass alloc] init];
}

- (void)doStuff
{
    // Do something interesting
}
@end
```

The prefix header `MyProj-Prefix.pch` contains:

```
#define MYCLASS MyClass
#define SOMEVAR @"Hello"
```

I have created a bridging header which contains:

```
#import "MyProj-Prefix.pch"
```

The project contains Objective-C code that uses the class definition, e.g.

```
[[MYCLASS myClass] doStuff];
```

I would like to mirror this in my new swift code. I *can* see and reference the defined variable, but the defined class isn't visible. e.g.

```
let someStr = SOMEVAR // This compiles
MYCLASS.myClass.doStuff() // MYCLASS isn't visible
```

Any pointers on how to achieve this? I'm not even sure if this is possible in swift.

Answer (score 2):

This problem would exist even if `#define MYCLASS MyClass` was in any other header, not necessarily in prefix header.  This is because preprocessor directives are generally not imported into Swift.  Simple macros are, however, imported if they can be mapped to global constants, which is possible for `SOMEVAR`, but not `MYCLASS`.  See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID17 .

One could use a typealias in Swift at the global scope:

```
typealias MYCLASS = MyClass
```

Of course, the typealias would have to be modified if `MYCLASS` was re-defined in the header.

This approach is not very helpful, unfortunately, if the definition of `MYCLASS` changes depending on where/how the code is built.  However, since the code must know quite a bit about the behavior common to the various classes that can be defined as `MYCLASS`, it might be possible to use protocols here, for example.

UPDATE:
After thinking about/playing with it some more and reading some other posts, e.g. [Using obj-c typedef in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31125549/using-obj-c-typedef-in-swift), here is a better solution, I think.  With this approach you don't need to change your Swift code if `MYCLASS` is re-`#define`d in Objective-C.

Somewhere in your Objective-C code, e.g. in the bridging header, add

```
typedef MYCLASS * _MYCLASS;
```

which will then allow you to do things like the following in Swift:

```
_MYCLASS.myClass().doStuff()
```

If you really insist on using `MYCLASS` in Swift for some reason, adding `typealias MYCLASS = _MYCLASS` in your Swift code will do the trick.